# Right index for timestamp field on Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE material
(
  mid bigserial NOT NULL,
...
  active_from timestamp without time zone,
....
  CONSTRAINT material_pkey PRIMARY KEY (mid),
)

CREATE INDEX i_test_t_year
  ON material
  USING btree
  (date_part('year'::text, active_from));
```

if I made sorting by mid field

```
select mid from material order by mid desc
"Index Only Scan Backward using material_pkey on material  (cost=0.29..3573.20 rows=100927 width=8)"
```

but if I use active_from for sorting

```
select * from material order by active_from desc
"Sort  (cost=12067.29..12319.61 rows=100927 width=16)"
"  Sort Key: active_from"
"  ->  Seq Scan on material  (cost=0.00..1953.27 rows=100927 width=16)"
```

Maybe index for active_from wrong? How to make right one for lower cost

Comment: The best index depends on the *whole* setup and the most common / most important queries. I seriously doubt that `select * from material order by active_from desc` is the actual query you are going to use. No `WHERE` conditions? Keeping your version of Postgres a secret is particularly unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

The index on date_part('year'::text, active_from) can't be used to sort by active_from; **you** know that sorting by that function and then by active_from gives the same order as simply sorting by active_from but postgresql doesn't. If you create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX i_test_t_year ON material (active_from);
```

then postgresql will be able to use it to answer the query:

```
Index Scan Backward using i_test_t_year on material  (cost=0.15..74.70 rows=1770 width=16)
```

However, remember that postgresql will only use the index if it thinks it will be faster than doing a sequential scan then sorting, so creating the correct index doesn't guarantee that it will be used for this query.

Comment: Ok, it's works I had "Index Scan Backward using i_test_t_year on material  (cost=0.29..3579.79 rows=100927 width=16)"

Comment: it's strange! If I make index like - CREATE INDEX i_test_t_year ON material (active_from DESC LAST); It not used in query. Why query with order not using in index with order

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to fully understand an index and I believe this will answer your question.

An index is literally a lookup stored in it's own memory next to the table. You literally look at the index and then it points to the rows to fetch.

If you look at your index, what you are storing is a TEXT value of the 'year' extracted from the "active_from" column.

So if you were to look at the index, it will look like a bunch of entries saying:

```
2015
2015
2014
2014
2013
etc.
```

They are stored as TEXT value, not as the timestamp.

In your query you are ordering it DESC as a timestamp value.

So it just doesn't match the index, as you have stored it.

If you put the ORDER BY in your query as "order by date_part('year'::text,active_from)" then it would call the index you put there.

So I suggest you just add the index on "active_from" with out parsing the date at all.